# When using chart.js to draw a line chart, if the peak is between two x values instead of "at a x value"

Tags: chart.js

[image]

As the example shows the peak of the black line is between 3 and 4, and I don't know how to do it.

The close I can get from w3c school example is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>

<script>
var xValues = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{ 
      data: [80,120,300,40,0,0],
      borderColor: "orange",
      fill: false
    }, { 
      data: [2,5,20,150,250,50],
      borderColor: "black",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false}
  }
});
</script>
```

Thanks for reading through.

Answer (score 0):

```
const labels = [0, '', '', '', 10, '', '', '', 20, '', '', '', 30, '', '', '', 40, '', '', '', 50];
```

Set the X labels this way; it will work.